# How to remove character from an SQL query in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got some dirty database of SQL to do a task. I have a column which can have data from different format like the following:

```
format 1 = 0000-0000000
format 2 = 0000.0000000
format 3 = 00000000000
```

The format 3 is a good format for my query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table where col='00000000000'"
```

I want to to remove these character in select query without disturbing the actual data.

Comment: Unless you *do* modify the data, your query will perform badly. The server won't be able to use any indexes that include the `col` column because the values you want to compare will be different from the ones stored in the index. Either clean up the data or add a persisted computed column that replaces the unwanted characters and use it in indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need `Replace` function. Just remove extra symbols during comparison

```
SELECT * from table 
where replace(replace(col, '-', ''), '.', '') ='00000000000'
```

Comment: This will result in a full table scan because the server won't be able to use any indexes that include `col`

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to format the string:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_StripString](@value as varchar(80), @KeepValues as varchar(80)) 
RETURNS varchar(80)
AS
begin
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @value) > 0
    Set @value = Stuff(@Valor, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @value), 1, '')    

    return @value
end
```

Then, assuming you just want numeric values:

```
SELECT * 
from table 
where dbo.fn_StripString(col, '%[^0-9]%') = '00000000000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` query

`Select * from table where col in ('00000000000','0000.0000000','0000-0000000')`